# Why is the ordering for the following collator support modules important?

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template

In the parachain template we see this snip of code:

```rust
// Collator support. The order of these 4 are important and shall not change.
        Authorship: pallet_authorship::{Pallet, Call, Storage} = 20,
        CollatorSelection: pallet_collator_selection::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>} = 21,
        Session: pallet_session::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event, Config<T>} = 22,
        Aura: pallet_aura::{Pallet, Storage, Config<T>} = 23,
        AuraExt: cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::{Pallet, Storage, Config} = 24,
```

My question is regarding the comment, why does the ordering of these pallets matter? Is this some quirk of `construct_runtime!`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your pallets in `construct_runtime!` defines the order in which `on_initialize`, `on_finalize` etc is being called. These pallets probably have some connection between them and require that `on_initialize` etc is called in this fixed order.

Edit: I just checked the code and I don't see any reason for `CollatorSelection` in there. For `Authorship` it makes sense, because it determines the current author in `on_initialize` and this should be done before `Session` may initializes a new session with new authorities.